# How do I make my script, receiving only the webpage's URL, parse its POST request's response?

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I access a specific webpage, it sends a specific POST request, the response to which I want to parse. How do I make my script, receiving only the webpage's URL, parse that specific request's response?

(Ideally, in Python.)

Comment: can you add the code you used? how did you open the page? did you use selenium? the requests module? or perhaps another library, you need to be more clear for us to help you

Comment: Yeah, so, I found the request using Chrome's DevTools. I figured that I need to parse its response, because the data I needed wasn't present in the HTML which I previously scraped using the 'requests' library. So far, I haven't been using Selenium. I've managed to do what I need manually by copying the cURL of the request (https://pasteboard.co/J4cu89V.jpg) and translating it into Python using https://curl.trillworks.com/. It gave me this code: https://pastebin.com/B0FTgiDu (I hid private data). I want this process to happen automatically for every (similar) webpage I access on that website.

Comment: I'm very new to web scraping and programming in general, but it seems that I need to somehow automatically generate 'headers' and 'data' for every page and then send a POST request using the 'requests' library.

Comment: The responses to those requests tell me clothes of what genders are present in the catalog. It's going to be different for every page in the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found out that the 'seleniumwire' library for Python is one way to access requests made by a browser when loading a page.